# What is the best way to reset a .onion address?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

I have no particular interest in finding a specific, non-random URL ([How do Hidden Services get .onion domains that aren't random?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-do-hidden-services-get-onion-domains-that-arent-random)), but would like to reset an onion address for a given hidden service.  What is the best way to get a new, random .onion address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a  `HiddenServiceDir` in your `torrc`. After you have stopped the Tor process, delete the above-mentioned directory and restart Tor. Now the directory contains two new files: `hostname` and `private_key`. The name in `hostname` is now different from the previous version.