# Looking to create a onion domain; need some help

Tags: onion-routing

Where can I find a place to register my own onion domain and is there any hosting sites that I could use for hosting for my [hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html)?

Answer (score 7):

## How-to:

Quoting hiddenwiki:

> Getting a .onion domain is not only free (they are automatically generated by Tor), but it is simple once you have completed the basic server installation procedure. If you are not familiar with servers find a friend or a tech whiz who can walk you through it. As with everything computer related, it is fairly difficult if you have never done it, but after you do it once, it is basically a breeze. The next time you generate a new address for yourself will take you only seconds.

---

Please visit these important sites. They will explain howto get your own hidden service running and how does it works:

- [How do onion addresses exactly work?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/672/how-do-onion-addresses-exactly-work)
- https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en
- https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en
- http://www.hiddenwiki.org/how-to-register-onion-domain.html

Those may be difficult for a newcomer to understand, but those are the basics of hosting an hidden service.

---

### Vanity domain

If you have ever seen some fancy .onion domain, you probably wanted to have your own cool and beautiful domain too.
Those are called *vanity domain*.
Dark web vanity domains are different from surface web domains. Dark web domains are intended to be hard to generate, because if you had ever been in hidden wiki, you could *theoretically* replace vanity domain with your own same looking domain.

Its really hard to notice a difference between say:
`http://torbrokerge7zxgq.onion/` and `http://torbrokerfna3yxf.onion/`.

### Generating vanity .onion address

Answer to [How do Hidden Services get .onion domains that aren't random?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-do-hidden-services-get-onion-domains-that-arent-random) have a great explanation:

> They use a tool like [Shallot](https://github.com/katmagic/Shallot) to brute-force the onion address.
>
> What Shallot does is to generate a private key in the same way that the Tor software does when generating a new hidden service address. It then manipulates the public key portion of the key to create new versions of the .onion address and checks through those to see if they match the desired address.
>
> It generates a new private key periodically. The keys generated by Shallot and other methods of brute forcing an onion address have a larger than average public key component but are syntactically fine and pass all tests ensuring that they are good keys.
>
> Shallot is run like this:
>
> ```
> $ ./shallot ^test
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------
>     Found matching pattern after 99133 tries: testvztz3tfoiofv.onion
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------
>     -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>     MIICXgIBAAKBgQC3R85m6NQaA1ZjaYqvz1hvFIjbL4RtKdJbG8hlC9xEBkvfr/BG
>     8Z5vDiUzdbDt8mEBuZUDanx80uGJvbXTgmczX0UlkEOgGiZ8RKpnsbKaf/EJNrIw
>     T7MSXQmWNcm22nDeViV7fwy+Usyal2RE5cdVCFsPtEbVZqCumlKkEgCyFwIDBAZ7
>     AoGBAJSa2cGuru/XhzJAEAIwHZbgPDnum9T/srOYxUKW6afHZeOu5S4Cclwb+xb/
>     pGOtzn71XZfCKMfiVdxB/f3XTcRrYB2VnBoNToTD7WfH6DksdDf4zunqiEjvxi9K
>     R+tKhxmF7OedrRt8wIhUmFd1E2Q9nbTHI6icdB4kR4QkYKZzAkEA5M6samK7+495
>     6SWpRXiePIs7sHKWuxdCrG7kW5RNJrv2CcGYwK46TPcaXBcRfM4eq9+9PGoKi0IO
>     gSpOZ5vRYQJBAM0QAZYTZ6ApD014x372MX1ZNofuYL/+XF8ZPZV6Sh4+9MUBuNPb
>     yL7BENDr6pX4Zm6OepvAphhCa4vGno2pHncCQQCQnfhUCHANU4bjtX4EOoI63WDq
>     UwBOeIWxu0YvGt7Z25Dg9CNz/aX8UZIoj6VyKxLRbR9+K3mNrNgaopW+ZDKzAkEA
>     ttgTK1ALe+3v+5H+Ez1SvFPREDFcHihrfD1Ipc5zicY9ixTArgdyZvk+Pi+AMBVV
>     sL2HWvjRLEAgRclvKfkwWwJAFtM+BIGRM5me+fMALuBBEtKnbJ6maflsyucErEb0
>     pIIBkovF5oyWO3lSBmtStJIANNkHOg8aXqjcgPKusDN7CQ==
>     -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> By passing it a regular expression, you can describe what you want your .onion address to look like. Using this hostname and private key you can create the hostname and private_key files that tor expects to find in the hidden service directory.

Comment: I recommend looking into Scallion if you want a vanity domain.

Comment: what is a vanity domain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_domain